# MySql COALESCE In Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I had scenario where I will join 2 dataframe's then want to calculate usage of 2 columns.Presently the logic in SQL want to convert to spark dataframe
`bml.Usage*COALESCE(u.ConValue,1) as acUsage` where bml is a table inner joined with 'u' table ..While in data frames `bml.join(u,seq("id"),"inner").Select(COALESCE ???)` how to perform this operation either through UDF

Comment: is your sqark-sql and dataframe methods working? if so why would you want to use udf?

Comment: My dataframe is not working using COALESCE ...How to use COALESCE in select statement